# How to properly reset angularjs v1 factory after certain function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory

I Made a factory that keeps the information in my scopes in a series of 6 pages. Now when the user completes the 6th page and pushes the object I want the factory to reset to empty arrays again.

I already tried a lot with the timeout and apply elements, also tried a lot of combinations to set the array to empty (`null`, `""`, `{}`). but it still loads the old information when I load the page again(page 1/6).

The submit function (That also needs to reset the scopes) is

```
$scope.send = function(){
    if(ArrayInfo.Checkmark == true){
        firebase.database().ref('lorem/' + ArrayInfo.Ordernumber).set({
          info: ArrayInfo,
          Dates: Dates,
          gasmeter: gasmeter,
          gasmeter1: gasmeter1  
        }).then(function(){
          firebase.database().ref('lorem2/' + ArrayInfo.currentYear).set({
            last_number: ArrayInfo.Ordervalue
          });
        }).then(function(){
          //ArrayInfo = {};
          setTimeout(function(){
            ArrayInfo = "";
            $scope.info = "";
            $scope.$apply();
            $scope.$digest();
          }, 50);

        });
      //close newrental
        setTimeout(function(){
          if (window.confirm('Information saved! You are ready to leave this screen? no changes possible after this point'))
          { 
            //disable back button in home 
            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
              disableBack: true
            });
            //go home
            $state.go("app.auth");
          }
          //error close newrental
          else
          {
             alert("Take your time");
          }
        }, 50);

    }
    //error send array
    else {
      alert("Please accept the terms and conditions.");
    }
  }
```

My factory looks like this

```
mainapp.factory("infoFactory", function(){
  ArrayInfo = {};
  placeholders = {
    "licenseone" : "img/placeholder.png",
    "licensetwo" : "img/placeholder.png",
    "licensethree" : "img/placeholder.png",
    "licensefour" : "img/placeholder.png",
    "imageone" : "img/front.png",
    "imagetwo" : "img/sideleft.png",
    "imagethree" : "img/back.png",
    "imagefour" : "img/sideright.png",
    "imagefive" : "img/roof.png",
    "imagesix" : "img/placeholder.png",
    "imageseven" : "img/placeholder.png",
    "imageeight" : "img/placeholder.png"
  };
  gasmeter = {
    "url" : "img/gas/gas1.png",
    "gasvalue" : "1"
  }
  gasmeter1 = {
    "url" : "img/gas/gas1.png",
    "gasvalue" : "1"
  }
  ArrayInfo.returned = false;
  RawDate = {};
  Dates = {};

  console.log(ArrayInfo);

  return ArrayInfo;
  return gasmeter;
  return gasmeter1;
  return placeholders;
  return RawDate;
  return Dates;
})
```

and I load the information in my controller like this

```
$scope.info = infoFactory;
$scope.Dates = Dates;
$scope.RawDate = RawDate;
$scope.gasmeter = gasmeter;
$scope.gasmeter1 = gasmeter1;
```

---

The angular version I am using is "3.6.6"

Comment: there is no "angular 3.6.6";  Angularjs is at 1.6.4 and Angular is at 4.1.0;  the 3.x branch was skipped entirely.

Comment: My bad, i confused my angularfire with my angular version. Its updated now.

Comment: I have multiple arrays so i figure i need multiple returns? Or do i need to call them by infoFactory.Dates by example?

Comment: @AlonEitan well that works! is there any way to easy reset it when setup like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you put `return` in your code, there's no use to include additional code after that, because it will never run. You need to return an `Object` instead.

```
mainapp.factory("infoFactory", function(){
  ArrayInfo = {};
  placeholders = {
    "licenseone" : "img/placeholder.png",
     // Rest of the images
  };
  gasmeter = {
    "url" : "img/gas/gas1.png",
    "gasvalue" : "1"
  }
  gasmeter1 = {
    "url" : "img/gas/gas1.png",
    "gasvalue" : "1"
  }
  ArrayInfo.returned = false;
  RawDate = {};
  Dates = {};

  console.log(ArrayInfo);

  return { 
    ArrayInfo: ArrayInfo, 
    gasmeter: gasmeter, 
    gasmeter1: gasmeter1, 
    placeholders: placeholders, 
    RawDate: RawDate, 
    Dates: Dates 
  };
})
```

Now you can inject `infoFactory` to the controller and use it like this: `infoFactory.RawDate`.

Now, if you want to reset the factory, you can add a function that reset all the data:

```
mainapp.factory("infoFactory", function(){
  // Save a reference to the current pointer of the factory, so you won't loose it inside other scopes  
  var self = this;

  self.params = {
       ArrayInfo: {},
       placeholders: {},
       gasmeter: {},
       gasmeter1: {},
       ArrayInfo: false,
       RawDate: {},
       Dates: {}
  };

  self.reset = function() {
     self.params.ArrayInfo = {};

     self.params.placeholders.licenseone = "img/placeholder.png";

     self.params.gasmeter.url = "img/gas/gas1.png";
     self.params.gasmeter.gasvalue = "1";

     self.params.gasmeter1.url = "img/gas/gas1.png";
     self.params.gasmeter1.gasvalue = "1";

     self.params.ArrayInfo.returned = false;

     self.params.RawDate = {};

     self.params.Dates = {};
  }
  self.reset(); // Call this function by default in order to initially set the factory properties 

  return { 
    reset: self.reset, // You can export the reset function and use it outside the factory too
    ArrayInfo: self.params.ArrayInfo, 
    gasmeter: self.params.gasmeter, 
    gasmeter1: self.params.gasmeter1, 
    placeholders: self.params.placeholders, 
    RawDate: self.params.RawDate, 
    Dates: self.params.Dates 
  };
})
```

Now when you have a reset function, you can use it like this **outside** the factory: `infoFactory.reset()` whenever you want to reset the data to the initial state. I created inside the factory a base object (`this.params = { .. }`) and saved inside it all the details properties, inside the `reset` function I have updated those properties **without** breaking the original references ([Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/goywpvna/1/)).

The above is just an example, but you can (or perhaps *should*) encapsulate the `params` of the factory, and only allow the user to control and change the values via helper functions. Example of how to do it:

```
mainapp.factory("infoFactory", function(){
  var self = this;

  self.params = {
     returned: false,
  };

  return {
     setReturned: function(val) { self.params.returned = val === true; },
     returned: function() { return self.params.returned; }
  }
});
```

The above example will *hide* the actual `params.returned` from the user outside the factory, and only allow it to set the *returned flag* via helper function, i.e `infoFactory.setReturned( true );` or `infoFactory.setReturned( false );`, and inside that `setReturned` function you can implement complex logic to validate the value sent to the function. Note that `infoFactory.setReturned( 'invalid value!!!' );` will set the `returned` flag to `false`  since i'm validating the value using the [strict === operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) - `val === true`.

Then, to get the value from the factory you call the `infoFactory.returned()` function - By using a function you're blocking outside access to the properties of the factory.

---

As a side note - Don't use `setTimeout(function(){ ... });` Use [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout) and [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$interval) and then you won't need `$scope.$apply();` + `$scope.$digest();` in order to manually run a digest cycle because it is being handeled nativaly by Angularjs for you

Comment: The first version of the Factory helps me alot, im kinda confused about the second Factory tho. It looks awesome piece of code but does'nt seem to work for me. My arrayinfo doesn't get defined properly using it. I'm using the same piece of code as with the first factory '$scope.info = infoFactory.ArrayInfo;'

Comment: I literally plugged the complete Factory in place of the old one. My controllers sees self. as undefined and the self.reset() is undefined ... Probally doing something wrong :)

Comment: Okay cool, My factory is exactly the code of the second snippet right now. Nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142974/discussion-between-jurjen-folkertsma-and-alon-eitan).

Comment: What do you need for that?

Comment: When using the second example. What is the best way to push data to my factory from my controller?

First i used this piece of code for example `ArrayInfo.Ordernumber = blabla;`

Now i could use `vm.infoFactory.ArrayInfo.Ordernumber = blabla;`
But that seems unnecessary long.

Comment: You should add a custom function to the factory (after `returned: function() { return self.params.returned; }` in my third snippet example, and do something like `addPlaceholder: function(name, placeholder) {  self.params.placeholders[name] = placeholder;  }` and then use that function  **outside** the factory `infoFactory.addPlaceholder( 'licenseFive', "img/placeholder.png" );`

Comment: I build in your code and i found out the problem is exactly the same as b4, the properties that are individual reset are at their default values. But it doesn't empty the generated array (ArrayInfo as an example).

Comment: @JurjenFolkertsma It's unfortunately getting out of the scope, can you please open a new question with updated details? Before that, you might want to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)  - You can iterate over the object properties and remove any property that is'nt suppose to be there by default

Comment: for now using code like `vm.infoFactory.ArrayInfo = {};` wil do the trick in the send function. For some reason that does work now. Thank you alot for the help, really helped!

Comment: Now im finding out that when using my reset code it doesnt take in the presets of the array, and after the reset my arrays are completely emty.

my code :

Comment: setTimeout(function(){
                      vm.infoFactory.ArrayInfo = {};
                      vm.infoFactory.Dates = {};
                      vm.infoFactory.RawDate = {};
                      vm.infoFactory.pdf = {};
                      vm.infoFactory.reset();
                    }, 5); 
                     //disable back button in home 
                    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                      disableBack: true
                    });
                    
                    //go home
                    $state.go("app.home");

Comment: when trying to log the reset function it tells me not defined 

console.log(vm.infoFactory.reset());